# How to Bold two letter in title

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I am using   [getwidget](https://pub.dev/packages/getwidget) and I want to bold two letter in title bar in this code

```
GFAccordion(
          contentBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
          collapsedTitleBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
          collapsedIcon: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 31, 45, 1),
          ),
          expandedIcon: Icon(
            Icons.minimize,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 31, 45, 1),
          ),
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 32,
          ),
          title: 'archIncubator',
          expandedTitleBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
          content:
              "Lobortis. In non finibus quam, a rhoncus est.",
        ),
```

Comment: What is `GFAccordion`?

Comment: Style of Accordion

Comment: are you using any package ?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.getwidget.dev/introduction/

Comment: Are you using getx/get?  consider include the tag

Comment: No. I didn't use

Comment: Which letters you would like bold

Answer (score 0):

Use `titleChild` instead of `title`. and provide `RichText`

[image]

```dart
 GFAccordion(
        contentBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
        collapsedTitleBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
        collapsedIcon: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 31, 45, 1),
        ),
        expandedIcon: Icon(
          Icons.minimize,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 31, 45, 1),
        ),
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 32,
        ),
        titleChild: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22,
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "arch",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "In",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.red),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "cubator",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        expandedTitleBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(137, 246, 246, 246),
        content: "Lobortis. In non finibus quam, a rhoncus est.",
      ),
```

Comment: Can't Add RichText to titleChild

Comment: What is the issue you get